# Home workout plan for a person who sits all the day for studying

Tags: workout-routines, home-exercise

I have a University Entrance Exam in next year and I aim to study at home every day as much as I can (near 12 hours per day). To avoid obesity, keeping my body and brain healthy and having better mood, I'm planning to do exercises at home. Can you please recommend some home workout plans that fits my conditions? I did this  [full body workout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAPCPjnU1wA) before (not regularly) and it is not very hard for me to bear the whole 20 minutes! Should I do this exercise every day or there are better plans?

Comment: You realize that studying 12 hours a day every day is not your best plan, yes? I can see treating it like a job, but take breaks, limit the hours and make time for life outside of the pages.